# Laravel 5, Bootstrap, and Less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, less, laravel-5

I'm just getting started with Laravel 5, and I followed this [guide](http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-bootstrap-htmlcss-framework-web-applications/) to install Bootstrap. It's my first time with Laravel, and I'm not familiar with responsive theming and related technologies.

I then went to [Startbootstrap](http://startbootstrap.com/) to try out one of the templates in the Laravel framework. I created a view for top bar of one of the templates by copying *only* the HTML, included `http://mysite/js/bootstrap.js` and `http://mysite/css/bootstrap.css` according to the guide, but when I rendered it on the browser (Firefox), I saw that classes like `.navbar-header` were being loaded from `nav.less`. I now do see that Laravel 5 originally comes with Less files, but they're outside of the `public` directory (`mysite/resources/assets/less/bootstrap/`), so they're not being used.

So my questions are..

1. That guide I linked gave me the impression that Bootstrap did not come with Laravel 5, but it seems like the Less version does. Am I supposed to use a Less compiler for the files at `mysite/resources/assets/less/bootstrap/` if I wanted to use Bootstrap that came with Laravel 5?
2. The path `mysite/css/less/navbar.less` shown in the browser doesn't actually exist in my installation. Furthermore, the CSS is actually coming from `http://mysite/css/bootstrap.css`. How did the browser generate `mysite/css/less/navbar.less`? See https://www.evernote.com/l/Ak-3I6SiUlhBd6Y_4NiX10LgrMt0vccqjiI .

Comment: Laravel uses [laravel elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir) on top of gulp in a build pipeline. Install npm + gulp (`npm install -g gulp && npm install`) and run `gulp watch`.

Comment: @Amelia, I followed the Laravel documentation and was able to run Elixir/Gulp, which generates `css/app.less`. It doesn't seem to be used, though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the LESS was compiled with source maps enabled and it seems that the Chrome **Enable CSS source maps** is also active. That's why you're seeing the actual mapped rule from the LESS file. The following article explain how that works and how to disable it:

> [Debug LESS with Chrome Developer Tools](http://robdodson.me/debug-less-with-chrome-developer-tools/)

In Firefox you can disable the CSS source mapping in the Developer Tool options, under the section **Style Editor** uncheck **Show original sources**. Also here's [a good article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps) that explains how source maps work (although it uses JS source maps as examples, the concept is the same).

---

The Bootstrap files that came with Laravel have no direct connection to the CSS files that you downloaded. In your `public/css/` directory you will have a `bootstrap.css` file, as well as a `bootstrap.css.map` file. If you open the `bootstrap.css` file you'll see that at the end of the file there is a line:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */
```

That tells the browser that there there is a source map file with that name, that contains mappings from the compiled CSS to the source code which was written in LESS.

If you open the `bootstrap.css.map` you'll see that, while most of it is gibberish for handling the mappings, at the very beginning there is an array of source paths that lists the LESS files that were compiled to form the CSS file. That is what the browser is reading and showing you in the CSS inspector. It doesn't really know what you have on your server, it just knows from the source map file that the rule for the `.navbar-header` class was defined in the `nav.less` file before it was compiled to CSS. This is to make it easier to find rule definitions after compilation.

Comment: I'm using Firefox. Is it the same idea?

Comment: Yep, the concept is the same, regardless of browser. I've updated my answer with the extra details needed.

Comment: Thanks! I see the option and unchecking it reveals the proper file at `css/bootstrap.css`. I also see `resources/assets/less/bootstrap/bootstrap.less`, which references `navbar.less`. But I'm still not seeing the connection between `css/bootstrap.css` (which I added separately from `http://getbootstrap.com`) and the files at `resources/...` (which came with Laravel 5) are related. How does that work? Running the task runner gulp mentioned by @Amelia generates `css/app.less` but not `css/bootstrap.css`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more detailed explanation.